# Get the records which are not created this year using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One is Contact Registration table and one is Payments table
One contact registration can have multiple payments. eg: 1 CR can have 15 payments

| ContactRegId | RegStatus | RenewalStatus | ExpiryDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Suspended | Pending | 2023-02-15 |
| 2345678 | Suspended | Complet | 2023-01-03 |
| 758948 | Registerd | Pending | 2023-02-15 |
| 3134232 | notregstd | Pending | 2023-01-03 |
| 435345 | Registerd | Pending | 2023-02-15 |
| 5636443 | notregstd | Pending | 2023-01-03 |

| ContactRegId | CreatedOn | PaymentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2021-05-10 | 43 |
| 123456 | 2020-09-11 | 42 |
| 123456 | 2019-03-30 | 21 |
| 123456 | 2018-12-10 | 46 |
| 758948 | 2022-09-14 | 24 |
| 758948 | 2021-08-17 | 423 |
| 758948 | 2020-07-03 | 432 |
| 758948 | 2019-06-23 | 437 |
| 758948 | 2018-09-15 | 138 |
| 435345 | 2022-09-11 | 2345 |
| 435345 | 2021-08-01 | 4234 |
| 435345 | 2020-07-12 | 436 |
| 435345 | 2019-04-14 | 438 |
| 435345 | 2018-01-16 | 433 |

I need the Contact Registration records which satisfies (RegStatus = Suspended or registered) and RenewalStatus = Pending from Contact registration table
and if the payments are not created this year

So the output should be

| ContactRegId | RegStatus | RenewalStatus | ExpiryDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Suspended | Pending | 2023-02-15 |

How to do this?

I tried using below query. But it didn't work.

```
select distinct cr.ContactRegId , COUNT(PaymentId) as count1
from contactregistration cr left join payments p
on cr.ContactRegId = p.ContactRegId 
where (cr.RegStatus   = 'Registerd' or cr.RegStatus   = 'Suspended')
and cr.RenewalStatus = 'Pending'
and  YEAR(p.CreatedOn) = YEAR(getdate()) 
group by cr.ContactRegId having COUNT(PaymentId) = 0
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Thats a pretty basic query and there are a lot of good tutorials out there.

Comment: yes, I have tried using below query but it didn't work.
select distinct cr.ContactRegId , COUNT(PaymentId) as count1
from contactregistration cr left join payments p
on cr.ContactRegId = p.ContactRegId 
where (cr.RegStatus   = 'Registerd' or cr.RegStatus   = 'Suspended')
and cr.RenewalStatus = 'Pending'
and  YEAR(p.CreatedOn) = YEAR(getdate()) 
group by cr.ContactRegId having COUNT(PaymentId) = 0

Comment: [edit] that into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need the Contact Registration records which satisfies (RegStatus = Suspended or registered ) and RenewalStatus = Pending from Contact registration table and if the payments are not created this year

You can filter the registration table with a subquery that ensures that the contact had no payment this year:

```
select r.*
from contactRegistration r
where r.RegStatus in ('Suspended', 'Registered')
    and r.RenewalStatus = 'Pending'
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from payments p
        where 
            p.ContactRegId = r.ContactRegId 
            and p.CreatedOn >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), 1, 1)
    )
```